# connected and separated sets proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(X, d)$ be a connected metric space and $A$ be a connected subset. If $A^{c}$ is the union of two separated sets $B$ and $C$, prove the following:

(1) $A \cup B$ and $A \cup C$ are connected.

(2) If $A$ is closed then $A \cup B$ and $A \cup C$ are also closed.

My attempt:

(1) I already have of a correct proof of this one but I also tried a different approach:

Proof.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $A \cup B$ is not connected. Then since it is disconnected there are open sets $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ such that $A \cup B \subseteq E_{1} \cup E_{2}$, $(A\cup B) \cap E_{1} \neq \phi$, $(A\cup B) \cap E_{2} \neq \phi$ and $(A\cup B)\cap E_{1} \cap E_{2} = \phi$.

Since $A \subseteq A \cup B$ and $A$ is connected we can say that $A$ lies in $E_{1}$ or $E_{2}$.

Assume $A$ lies in $E_{1}$. Then since $A \cup E_{2} \neq \emptyset$, we see that $E_{1} \cap E_{2} \neq \emptyset$ (Not sure how to show this). Contradiction!

By symmetry, the same follows if we assume $A$ lies in $E_{2}$.

The same proof also applies to $A \cup C$ and so $A \cup B$ and $A \cup C$ are connected.

QED.

(2) Not sure how to do this one.

Is the proof for (1) correct? For (2) I have no idea what to do. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: (1) is false. Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$ with the discrete metric, and let $A=\{0\}$, $B=\{1\}$, and $C=\{2\}$. Then $A$ is connected, $B$ and $C$ are separated sets in $X\setminus A$, and $A\cup B$ and $A\cup C$ are not connected. Or are you using $A^c$ to mean $\operatorname{cl}(A)$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No, $A^c$ is the complement.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I suppose this would then be a better proof of (1): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056573/assume-a-subset-mathbbrn-is-connected-such-that-ac-is-separated-by-b

Comment: That one is true, because the space in which everything is taking place is connected; yours would be true if you required $X$ to be connected.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh my bad! The question was supposed to say that $X$ is connected. I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Any proofs for (2)?

Comment: For (2) you know that $C\cap\operatorname{cl}B=\varnothing$, so $C=X\setminus(A\cup\operatorname{cl}B)$.